# Efficient way to ban someone from my java program?

Tags: java, macos, ip

I have a game programmed in java.
As in every game though, there are people that you would like to keep off of it.
Now, if I just ban the email address, username, ip address, host address, anything like that.
It's quite easy for someone to just change their ip quickly, or use a VPN, and make a new account under a new username and email, and continue doing what they were doing.
I have also tried getting their MAC address. However they have to use a client to log in, and a lot of them can deobfuscate it (I have obfuscated it) and just change where I'm sending the MAC address via the attachment in the channel.
Others can just google and find easy ways to scramble their MAC addresses.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: A lot of games (if not all) have this problem, not sure if there is a real way to completely ban someone without them finding some way to come back.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly saying that their MAC address has been banned, but instead ban their IP address, so that scrambling their MAC doesn't help? ;)

Comment: Shhhh Simon, you trying to get me banned man? :-@

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to ban then, how about getting them to lose interest and quit?  Use the honeypot idea.  Add a hidden user-level "no-fun preference" to the game that just makes it far less fun, but not obviously so.  Perhaps the game runs slow, or you can't see as far, or it gets incredibly difficult very quickly.  Use your imagination.

Then the next time you discover your "special" user, don't ban him--set the hidden no-fun preference for him.   Hopefully he will lose interest and leave you alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is one giant map, as opposed to levels.
Also, the individuals that I am trying to rid from my game try to hack things more just to anger myself and the other owner, rather than to better themselves in the game.

Comment: As a variant of this, any time you have a new alpha version of the game for which you need testers, redirect them to that version. They get to run untested software, you get free testing.

Comment: @CodyThompson How about a map with special topology, so that no matter how far they travel, and what direction they travel in, they get back to the same place?

Comment: @CodyThompson 50% of the time it takes your troll to a random location instead of where he intended?  Perhaps where something is likely to kill or annoy him?  If by "hack things" you mean exploit security holes, add a key logger, consider it free intrusion detection, and fix the holes :)

Comment: There's no way to identify someone if they've made a new account though, and change their information like stated above. I'd have to set the above sort of "troll things" to one account. When they see this on their account, they can just make a new one. By hack, I mean editing the game client to somehow benefit themselves in game. We have fixed them all now. They also come on just to be a nuisance now.

Comment: The problem is that it is nearly impossible to ban someone because they can create new accounts.  I'm suggesting changing the problem in such a way that 1) they don't feel the need to create a new account (they don't realize they've been detected) and 2) they get annoyed with the game enough to abandon the game.  Once you've manually detected a troll user, flag their account with something that causes (2) to happen without them creating a new account.